# Formatting decimal places by row and then column

Tags: r

I am trying to produce a table for a clinical trial report. I have parameters listed down the left side and summary stats (mean, median, etc) across the top (it's the best format to use for space). I need extra precision on one row where the numbers are quite small. Is it at all possible to first set the number of decimal places by a row and then update what's left by column? I have a previous report generated in SAS by someone else that seems to have been able to achieve this, but I don't know how to replicate the same in R.

Say in this toy data, I first wanted to set a specific row (let's say row 5) to have 5 decimal places and then the rest of the data to have 3. Is it possible?

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(cbind(var1 = rnorm(10, 10, 1),
                       var2 = rnorm(10, 10, 1),
                       var3 = rnorm(10, 10, 1)))

> df
        var1      var2      var3
1  10.154649 10.705971  8.830994
2   8.574063 10.773831  9.437210
3   9.177850 10.639665 10.169646
4  10.791533  8.560607  9.933333
5  11.046810  9.220135  7.627125
6  11.532739  8.990035 10.993207
7   9.688523 10.078636  9.728344
8   8.048989 10.203599  8.484947
9  10.210700  9.414636  9.365975
10  9.766223 10.137261  8.997470

# Using formatC to set decimal places for a column
df <- df |> 
  mutate(var2 = formatC(var2, format = "f", digits = 2))
```

Comment: One option would be to split the rows out using `dplyr::slice`, format each separately and then combine again with `dplyr::bind_rows`, taking due care of the row numbers (which `slice` unfortunately discards).

Comment: How are you displaying/printing this data?  It may be more appropriate to do the formatting at that stage rather than trying to change the attribute at this level. If you haven't already chosen a method then `formattable` and `kableExtra` are among the packages that can do it - try searching some tutorials for those to see which suits your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number` inside `if_else`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    var2 = if_else(
      row_number() == 5, 
      formatC(var2, format = "f", digits = 5), 
      formatC(var2, format = "f", digits = 3)
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(cbind(var1 = rnorm(10, 10, 1),
                   var2 = rnorm(10, 10, 1),
                   var3 = rnorm(10, 10, 1)))

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
df[i,] <- formatC(as.numeric(df[i,]), format = "f", digits = 3)
}

df[5,] <- formatC(as.numeric(df[5,]), format = "f", digits = 5)
df
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with this solution is that you're just adding zero's back in, not keeping the original precision

Comment: ah sorry I didn't notice

Comment: changing the for sentence like this "for (i in c(1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10)) {" it works